# How to pass error details when using StatusCodePagesWithRedirects in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application and I'm attempting to handle HTTP responses with status codes between 400 and 599 by using `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`.

In `Startup.cs` I've added the following:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error");
```

My Error controller is empty except for the following action (which was taken from the default scaffolded Home controller):

```
[Route("Error")]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

This works perfectly when I call `return new BadRequestResult();` or `return NotFound();` from one of my controllers, but when I try to return an error with more detail (such as including an error object) the controller action is never called and the body of the response is displayed on screen as plaintext instead. As an example, the following statement does not trigger the Error controller:

```
context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult({ Errors = errors });
```

If I use the following statement instead, the middleware is correctly called:

```
context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
```

This appears to be working as designed, as the documentation states that `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` "checks for responses with status codes between 400 and 599 *that do not have a body*" (emphasis mine) and the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/ea27a4e56c12a08423d3b2b296b73cbbfa2063ab/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesMiddleware.cs#L41) backs this up.

I want to include more information on my error page (such as user friendly error messages where appropriate) but I can't figure out how I can pass the data across effectively using the middleware since I'm trying to avoid my controllers knowing too much about how errors are handled so that the logic can be contained in one place and potentially changed later.

Is there a way to return a HTTP error that has additional information but will still get picked up by `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the exception handling middleware works. I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but it looks like you're attempting to return `BadRequest` from middleware or an action filter. If you want to intercept some error there, you should simply allow the exception to bubble up (or throw one), not return a response, as that way, you'll keep the context of what happened.

Inside your error action, you can use HTTP feature interfaces to get the data you're looking for then. For example, there's:

```
var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
```

If there was an exception, you can access it then via `exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error`. There's also `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature`, which you can use to get the original URL of the request for things like 404s:

```
var statusCodeReExecuteFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
if (statusCodeReExecuteFeature != null)
{
    OriginalURL =
        statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPathBase
        + statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPath
        + statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalQueryString;
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute)

Depending on exactly what you're doing, there might be other ways as well.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning, that using IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature makes sense only in conjunction with UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(), otherwise it seems to be null when UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects() was used.

Answer (score 0):

The below is not exactly what you need (passing an error details/an error object) but it seems like you **can** pass an error code, at least in ASP.NET Core.

If you look at the documentation for [UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#usestatuscodepageswithredirects), it says that you can pass a status code, since the url template may contain such parameter:

```cs
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/MyStatusCode?code={0}");
```

Then in your MyStatusCode.cshtml you can intercept it like:

```cs
@{
    var codeStr = Context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("code") ? Context.Request.Query["code"].ToString() : "-1";
}
```